# File modification time, unix timestamp, timezone in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to just keep today's log in logs directory.

```
use POSIX qw(mktime);
use Time::Local;
my $file="20130204.log";
print "$file\t";
open my $fh,'<',$file;
my $modtime = (stat($fh))[9];
print "modtime:$modtime\n";
my $time = timelocal(59,59,23,4,2,2013);
print "Time::Local::time(2013-2-4 23:59:59) => $time\n";
$time = mktime(59,59,59,4,2,2013-1900,0,0);
print "mktime(2013-2-4 23:59:59) => $time\n";
```

results:

```
20130204.log        modtime:1359989999
Time::Local::time(2013-2-4 23:59:59) => 1362409199
mktime(2013-2-4 23:59:59) => 1362538799
```

`date`: `Tue Feb  5 10:57:00 JST 2013`

`ls -l`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 945203711 Feb  4 23:59 20130204.log
```

`date -d '2013-02-04 23:59:59' +%s`: 1359989999

Why Time::Local::time and mktime do not give me 1359989999?

Comment: you can stat a filename, you don't have to open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan = 0, 1900 = 0

```
$time = timelocal(59,59,23,4,2-1,2013-1900);
$time = mktime(59,59,59,4,2-1,2013-1900,0,0);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an convenient way to get the unix timestamp of everyday's 00:00:00 using Perl's core libs?

Comment: @Sato everyday's? like in a range?

Comment: @ysth sorry, I execute this script everyday, I want to get the unix timestamp of "today's 00:00:00"

Comment: `timelocal(0,0,0, (localtime)[3,4,5])`. Don't ask new questions in comments, please.

Comment: @Sato: note that not every day *has* a 00:00:00, e.g. `$ENV{TZ}="America/Sao_Paulo"; POSIX::tzset(); print scalar localtime timelocal(0,0,0,21,9,112)`